# JavaScript backgroundImage property

Tags: javascript, background

there is one box and it has an image (id) inside and I want to move it to another box as an image
my code
i have 2 box with id
let image = document.getElementById("image").value;
let output_picture = document.getElementById("output_picture")
output_picture.innerText=output_picture.style.backgroundImage=`url(${image})`;
and how to do

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is a "box".  But suppose your img=document.getElementById(imgid).  To move it to another element, for example a DIV with javascript variable div, then you can just do div.append(img) and it will move.

Comment: box equals div i put a link to the picture on one div and i want to transfer it to the other div as a picture